# Can't use MediaQuery inside a ListView

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I am trying to make my container take up 80% of the space available. It works when I replace `ListView` with a `Column` but it doesn't work when I use a `ListView`. Why does it behave like that?

Here is my code:

```
ListView(
 children: <Widget>[
  Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
  )
 ]
)
```

Comment: you need a `Row` widget with two children: one with `flex: 8` and second with `flex:2` - more: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#sizing-widgets

Comment: @pskink Thanks for responding again. This time it works. Kindly post it as an answer here as well as add some explanation so I can mark it correct.

Comment: write a self answer then...

Comment: @pskink Are you sure? I want to give you 25 reputation points for your answer.

Comment: Ok. I will post one now @pskink. Tysm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big credit to pskink for his solution. He solved it by using a `Row` widget along with three `Expanded` widgets.Setting the `Flex` property of each `Expanded` widget allows me to make my container to take 80% of the width.      Here is how I did it based on @pskink's Solution:

```
Row(
 children: <Widget>[
  Expanded(
    flex: 1,
    child: SizedBox(),
  ),
  Expanded(
    flex: 8,
    child: Container()
  ),
  Expanded(
    flex: 1,
    child: SizedBox(),
  ),
 ]
)
```

Comment: it should be `Row`, not `ListView`?

Comment: @pskink oh yeah. Sorry mistyped there.